# Method '+' called on null on some devices

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error "NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: +()"

But on the simulator and my phone, I can see the page perfectly and no error is shown. When other people installed the app on their devices, they get this error. I'm not sure why I can't reproduce it on debugging, but leaves me unsure on what to fix.

This is the only code snippets where I use +

```
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("Member since_") + "${timeago.format(user.timestamp.toDate())}",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45))
```

is it wrong to use + like this to combine strings? It has worked before, and still works on the simulator like I said.

Comment: so is "Member since_" really your key in the translation file? With a space? To be sure, why not refactor out the translation to a variable and print it out and then use it via Text("$myVar ${timeago.format(user.timestamp.toDate())}"); Furthermore its weird that your i18n lib cant handle parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on ${timeago.format(user.timestamp.toDate())} because this the only varialbe here(Please make sure your JSON translate "Member since_"), Maybe there is null on user.timestamp.toDate()
So you should use safe null variable like this:

```
final String timeRegist = user?.timestamp?.toDate() ?? '';

Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("Member since_") + "$timeRegist )}",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45))
```

Comment: Oops you are right haha json file wasn't translating member since_ cause in one of the files I was missing the "_" my bad! Thanks for pointing it out, I was overlooking that.